# Dont want array in table

Tags: php, mysql

My code

```
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) VALUES('$insertID','" . $capture_field_vals . "')";
    mysql_query($insert2);
```

And I get

```
ContactID       numbers  
1               421312, 123123, 3434543, 123423, 98797
```

What I want

```
ContactID     numbers
1             421312
1             123123
1             3434543
1             123423
1             98797
```

Please help me, I don't get it how to do this

Comment: are you still using mysql_query extension, it has been deprecated.

Comment: Yea, but mysqli dont work, idk why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array using `explode()`, then loop over them and insert them into the table.

```
$numbers = explode(',', $capture_field_vals);
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
    $n = trim($n);
    if (strlen($n) > 0) {
        $insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers (contactID, numbers) VALUES ('$insertID', '$n')";
        mysql_query($insert2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `$capture_field_vals` have an extra comma at the beginning or end?

Comment: $capture_field_vals .= $text_field1 .", ";

Comment: Why are you adding an extra comma? Don't do that.

Comment: where I adding this ?

Comment: OK, if you can't get rid of the extra comma, use the new version that checks for an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `String` to `Array` and loop through `insert` operation

```
$string2Array = explode(",", $capture_field_vals);
foreach($string2Array as $key=>$value){
 $insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) VALUES('$insertID','" . $value. "')";
 mysql_query($insert2);
}
```

**Note**: Don't use `mysql_*` because it has been deprecated. try to use `PDO`

**As per your comments, the value `$_POST["mytext"]` as `Array`. So you don't need to convert as string. please check the following code.**

```
if($_POST["mytext"]){
 foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key=>$value){
  $insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) VALUES('$insertID','" . $value. "')";
  mysql_query($insert2);
 }
}
```

Comment: $capture_field_vals1 ="";
       foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key1 => $text_field1){
        $capture_field_vals1 .= $text_field1 .", ";
       }

Comment: i have this, this is not what I want ?

Comment: Updated my answer..please check it. the value that you are getting as Array. So you don't need to convert as string. please check the following code.

Comment: I cant, Vote Up requires 15 reputation. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP's explode function.

When you are printing value in array:

$tempNum = explode(',' $result_set['numbers']);

And loop `$tempNum`

Answer (score 0):

Explode them first. Then generate a single query. No need to run the inside the `foreach` loop.Try with -

```
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) VALUES ";
$fields = explode(',', $capture_field_vals);
$values = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $values[] ="('$insertID', '".$field."')"; 
}
$insert2 .= implode(',', $values);
mysql_query($insert2);
```

Avoid using `mysql` functions since they are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = explode(",", $capture_field_vals);
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $insert2 = "INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) "
        . "VALUES('" . $insertID . "','" . trim($value) . "')";
    mysql_query($insert2);
}
```

NOTES:

- Do not use `mysql` functions since they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.
- Avoid sql injections by escaping your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Might be good idea to:
1. switch do mysqli, 
2. use prepared statements for security and clarity and 
3. use transaction to maintain database integrity when inserting a few rows representing single relation

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

...
$db->autocommit(FALSE);
$statment = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO numbers(ContactID, numbers) VALUES(?,?)");
foreach (explode(',', $capture_field_vals) as $field_val){
    try{
        $statement->bind_param('ss', $insertID, $field_val);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $db->rollback();
    }
}
$db->commit();
```